# Growing calls, calls have grown

Tags: word-order

I'm wondering if 'calls have grown for X to be Y-ed' is an acceptable substitute for 'there have been growing calls for X to be Y-ed'?

To clarify, these are examples of the latter from the first page of Google search results:
'There have been growing calls by some eco-activists and developing countries for powerhouse states to foot the bill for climate change.'
or 'There have been growing calls for St David's Day to be made a bank holiday in Wales'

Comment: Hello.f. What does your research show (are there many hits in a Google search for "calls have grown"? Are they mainly relevant (not say << Jim calls "have grown 3" in the last year!" >> ) Are they mainly different  rather than repeats? Do the sources look reasonably articulate?)

Comment: This X and Y business never really works out, except in math. IDK what what the context is, a call center? Or 'Calls have grown for Billy the Kid to be hanged' (if there were phones back then) or like what?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs I've added some examples, cheers. I'm not sure if it's as common in American english

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking about this very specific format rather than other uses of "calls have grown" e.g. "Calls have grown for an independent and impartial investigation into the killing of veteran Al Jazeera journalist Shireen Abu Akleh" or "Calls have grown for a way to try to punish Russian leaders for the crime of aggression"? Do you think "calls have grown for an inquiry" (period) should be different to "calls have grown for an inquiry to be established"?